# gadgets in ROP on AVR architecture

Tags: c, security, assembly, avr

Please for ROP refer to [this paper](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~hovav/papers/rbss12.html)

I'm building the gadget catalog for AVR-8bit but I have some doubts. 
I'll ask my question using the following example.

In order to have v1=v1+v2; (v1 and v2 are variables)
the corresponding assembly is:

```
ldi r17, #value
ldi  r18, #value
add r18,r17;
```

or

```
ldi r17, #value
mov r1, r17;
ldi  r18, #value
add r18,r1;
```

or

```
ldi r17, #value
ldi  r18, #value
mov r1, r18;
add r1,r17;
```

or

```
ldi r17, #value
mov r1, r17;
ldi r18, #value
mov r2, r18;
add r2,r1;
```

Will the gadget be the following?

```
ldi r#, #value;
ldi r#, value;
add r#, r#;
ret
```

or just the following combined with `ldi r#,r#; ret` and with the combination with `mov`?

```
add r#,r#;
ret
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ldi` is loading a constant and there is not much point in adding two constants at runtime. As such, your gadget will be the `add; ret` only, and you'll want to ensure the two operands are in the appropriate registers by using other gadgets.

It might make sense to have a gadget for adding a constant to a register, though.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. Would you please give me an example to make clear this sentence: "you'll want to ensure the two operands are in the appropriate registers by using other gadgets.". Is this point related to the algorithm that search the gadgets or is related to the gadget itself?